# How to increase the pointsize of the point-markers in the legend of a cluster-chart?

Tags: legending, charts, data-structures

I start the following mock data set:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 700}, {10^4, 2}];
```

I use k to define the number of cluster points:

```
k = 9;
```

Then I build a cluster chart with a legend as follows:

```
primarycolors = {Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Magenta, Cyan, LightGray, Black};

primarycolorsnames = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", 
   "Magenta", "Cyan", "Light Gray", "Black"};

labels = Row[{primarycolorsnames[[#]], " - cluster"}] & /@ 
   Range[1, k];

plot = ListPlot[FindClusters[data, k, Method -> "KMeans"], 
  AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"2019 HWOL Average Monthly Job Ads", 
    "Annual Average Job Openings"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 16, Bold], ImageSize -> 600, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[Framed["Macondo Region"], 16, Black, Bold, 
    Background -> Lighter[Yellow]], PlotStyle -> primarycolors, 
  PlotLegends -> labels]
```

My question is: How can I increase the pointsize of the point-markers in the legend without affecting the pointsize of the points in the cluster-chart?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
PlotLegends -> PointLegend[labels, LegendMarkerSize -> 15]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[labels, LegendMarkers -> {"Bubble", 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @kglr ! I accept your answers! Have a great weekend!